# Physical effects of large detuning conditions in adiabatically eliminates cavity mode?

Tags: atomic-physics, laser, adiabatic, cold-atoms, cavity-qed

A simple question: how to adiabatically eliminates cavity mode in this thesis: [here is arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.12491)/[journal link of it](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.106.043711) page2, just above equation (2):

> such that we can adiabatically eliminate the cavity degrees of freedom over a coarse-grained timescale [26]

1. I tried to download this reference thesis [[26]](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.129.063601), but after I read through this thesis, I still can't solve this issue, can somebody give me some advice please?
2. Physical effects of large detuning conditions in adiabatically eliminates cavity mode?assume the cavity is in the dispersive regime

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.